# TClientDataSet CreateDataset Memory Leak

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, memory-table, in-memory-tables

I am creating a new component, which inherits from TClientDataSet and it causes a memory leak. I've created a demo to reproduce the error (without need to share myCustomComponent). How can i solve this memory leak problem?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ClientDataSet1.Close;
   ClientDataSet1.Tag := 1;
   ClientDataSet1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1BeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   if ClientDataSet1.Tag = 1 then
   begin
      ClientDataSet1.Tag := 0;
      ClientDataSet1.Fields.Clear;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Clear;
      ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Collection', ftString, 50);
      ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Find('Collection').CreateField(ClientDataSet1);
      ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
   end;
end;
```

FastMM Event Log File:

```
--------------------------------2017/6/19 12:00:21--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 68

This block was allocated by thread 0x4FA8, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
418CD6 [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][DebugAllocMem$qqri][9900]
407276 [System.pas][System][AllocMem$qqri][4557]
65F91B [Datasnap.DBClient.pas][Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.AllocKeyBuffers$qqrv][3965]
6598AE [Datasnap.DBClient.pas][Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.InternalOpen$qqrv][1514]
623BC8 [Data.DB.pas][Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.DoInternalOpen$qqrv][12527]
623C77 [Data.DB.pas][Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.OpenCursor$qqro][12556]
65885B [Datasnap.DBClient.pas][Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.OpenCursor$qqro][1282]
623B2F [Data.DB.pas][Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.SetActive$qqro][12508]
62396B [Data.DB.pas][Data.DB][Db.TDataSet.Open$qqrv][12464]
65BE16 [Datasnap.DBClient.pas][Datasnap.DBClient][Dbclient.TCustomClientDataSet.CreateDataSet$qqrv][2342]
706827 [Unit1.pas][Unit1][TForm1.ClientDataSet1BeforeOpen$qqrp16Data.Db.TDataSet][64]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

The allocation number is: 1092

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EF776F0:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F1 7F B4 7C
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 C1 70 F7 7E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
73 04 00 00 D6 8C 41 00 76 72 40 00 1B F9 65 00 AE 98 65 00 C8 3B 62 00 77 3C 62 00 5B 88 65 00
2F 3B 62 00 6B 39 62 00 F4 65 70 00 D5 A7 53 00 A8 4F 00 00 A8 4F 00 00 AA 72 40 00 BE F5 60 00
AF F9 65 00 FA 9A 65 00 B8 3C 62 00 06 8C 65 00 9C 3B 62 00 F7 31 62 00 3C 8B 41 00 51 8B 41 00
29 7A 65 00 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 69 F3 D9 86 E4 FB 71 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ñ    ´  |
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  Á  p  ÷  ~  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
s  .  .  .  Ö  Œ  A  .  v  r  @  .  .  ù  e  .  ®  ˜  e  .  È  ;  b  .  w  <  b  .  [  ˆ  e  .
/  ;  b  .  k  9  b  .  ô  e  p  .  Õ  §  S  .  ¨  O  .  .  ¨  O  .  .  ª  r  @  .  ¾  õ  `  .
¯  ù  e  .  ú  š  e  .  ¸  <  b  .  .  Œ  e  .  œ  ;  b  .  ÷  1  b  .  <  ‹  A  .  Q  ‹  A  .
)  z  e  .  <  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  i  ó  Ù  †  ä  û  q  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
```

---

When trying @victoria 's code i get below error (althoug ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown does not raise anything) from fastMM then I realised FastMM confused me. I've reintroduced Open method and moved this code to there (without calling inherited or Open) and ReportMemoryLeaksOnShuntdown shows no leak but i could not understand why FastMM raises.

[image]

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 68

This block was allocated by thread 0x4918, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
4DB29E54 
4DB28419 
4DB21AA9 
4DB1FB5B 
7711F11C [VirtualQuery]
33B8FD9 [GetFrameBasedStackTrace]
33B901C [GetFrameBasedStackTrace]
77983431 [Unknown function at RtlQueryPerformanceCounter]
33B9336 [GetRawStackTrace]
417A0E [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][CalculateHeaderCheckSum$qqrp29Fastmm4.TFullDebugBlockHeader][9080]
417A1D [FastMM4.pas][FastMM4][UpdateHeaderAndFooterCheckSums$qqrp29Fastmm4.TFullDebugBlockHeader][9090]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

The allocation number is: 1060

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EF76FA0:
3C 00 B4 4D 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3F 00 00 00 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 43 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 01 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00
8C A3 AB 60 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
45 04 00 00 E8 A1 40 00 A3 AC 40 00 B5 F6 40 00 A0 BD 65 00 79 68 70 00 D5 A7 53 00 47 1F 55 00
55 2A 55 00 65 A2 53 00 38 70 3F 75 DD B4 04 74 18 49 00 00 18 49 00 00 AA 72 40 00 85 A2 40 00
3B BE 65 00 79 68 70 00 D5 A7 53 00 47 1F 55 00 55 2A 55 00 65 A2 53 00 38 70 3F 75 DD B4 04 74
89 B5 04 74 1B 00 00 00 E9 FD 01 00 04 D3 19 CB E4 FB 71 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 FB 2C E6 34 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
<  .  ´  M  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ?  .  .  .  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  C  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
Œ  £  «  `  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
E  .  .  .  è  ¡  @  .  £  ¬  @  .  µ  ö  @  .     ½  e  .  y  h  p  .  Õ  §  S  .  G  .  U  .
U  *  U  .  e  ¢  S  .  8  p  ?  u  İ  ´  .  t  .  I  .  .  .  I  .  .  ª  r  @  .  …  ¢  @  .
;  ¾  e  .  y  h  p  .  Õ  §  S  .  G  .  U  .  U  *  U  .  e  ¢  S  .  8  p  ?  u  İ  ´  .  t
‰  µ  .  t  .  .  .  .  é  ı  .  .  .  Ó  .  Ë  ä  û  q  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
€  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  û  ,  æ  4  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €
```

Comment: Looks like the data set is Opened twice. You should have realised something was wrong with your code when you encountered the stack overflow that led to your `Tag` re-entrancy hack. As to what the solution is, hard to say. I'd imagine that you just need to move that code out of `OnBeforeOpen` and place it before the call to `Open`. Get rid of that dire `Tag` hack. And when an event handler passes you an instance, use it rather than using the field from the class.

Comment: You create dataset and open it. Not open it and before it's opened you create it.

Comment: I have overried DoBeforeOpen procedure I use the code which is written in BeforeOpen in that section. I do not want programmers to call CreateDataSet externally, so i want to put it in my components DoBeforeOpen method.

Comment: @Victoria if i do not call TClientDataset.CreateDataSet method before opening dataset, i get  "Missng data provider or data packet" error when calling ClientDataSet1.Open

Comment: I don't think you read the call stack, or my comment. Please do so. Try to think about your problem, using the rich information that you have. Don't just give up on it.

Comment: doesnt createdataset also opens it ?

Comment: Sorry, `Open` is meant for provider (most often provider with SQL query). Just add fields, call `CreateDataset` and start adding records. @GuidoG, it does.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry but I did not understand what you mean exactly. And you are right after calling CreateDataSet method beforeopen event is fired again because of that reason I used tag re-entrancy hack. This code is not my working code, it is only for reporduce the error case. I call a webservice in before open event, create ClientDataset's fields and call CreateDataSet in DeBeforeOpen method and in DoAfterOpen method fill the data.

Comment: You need to do exactly what I said. Move that code out of `OnBeforeOpen` and execute it before you call `Open` and/or `CreateDataSet`.

Answer (score 3):

Do not define and create your dataset in the **BeforeOpen** event. To create (and open) in-memory dataset do:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Close;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Clear;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Collection', ftString, 50);
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
end;
```

To add record do:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonAppendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Append;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Collection').AsString := 'My collection';
  ClientDataSet1.Post;
end;
```

To edit current record do:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonUpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Collection').AsString := 'My collection upd.';
  ClientDataSet1.Post;
end;
```